# Translation for "bizzarro ammazzatore" (1642)

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, etymology

In 1642, the painter and biographer Giovanni Baglione used the expression *bizzarro ammazzatore* to qualify one of his contemporaries. The full sentence is quoted below. I understand what he's saying but have a problem with the expression itself. A bizarre murderer? An odd killer? It seems unnecessarily redundant. Unless there is a softer meaning to *ammazzatore*? How would you translate it, bearing in mind it's ancient Italian?

"E se havesse havuto l'animo volto alla professione, e non impiegato alle smargiasserie, e fare il furioso, e 'l bizzarro ammazzatore, molto più haverebbe fatto,..."

Comment: I think that the use of "bizarre" makes sense within the sentence context. Why do you think it is redundant?

Comment: Bizarre, meaning unconventional or unusual, is redundant with murderer, which is itself unconventional and unusual. Unless Baglione means that, as a murderer, he was unconventional, but I don't think so.

Comment: I think it is just Baglione's writing style, nothing more than that.

Comment: I'm afraid that in 1642 killing people was not always unconventional and unusual.

Comment: I second CasaMich's remark that killing in itself, and even more so in the 17th century, is not “bizarre”. Perhaps that chap killed people in especially fancy ways? (And [*ammazzatore* doesn's seem to have other meanings than “someone who kills”](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?E=4145;-2037802148;&c1=113;-7;3;-176437357;-1092164176;&c2=131;64;65;40;67;1;128;32;3;0;64;1;131;64;3;51;167;64;128;1025;3;0;75;12;128;63;65;40;1856636988;-184005499;&qi=AMMAZZATORE&q1=null&q2=null&q3=null&q4=null&qr=null&num=20&o=115;-38489505;-1185594668;&idV=978322;-464420555;1536957649;&TDE=&TDNE=).)

Comment: Moreover, this SE website is not to ask how to say things *in English*, since it is about Italian, not English (ELU.SE and ELL.SE are the ones). What we can do, if we are able to, is to help you understand what a word or phrase means.

Comment: How to say things in English is not the issue. What the expression  _bizzarro ammazzatore_ meant in 17th century Italian is what I was asking. And for me to understand it it's easier if the explanation is in English (or French actually). Thanks for the link.

Comment: Fine, JeanB, we agree on this; it's just that your «How would you translate it...» seemed to be asking for a translation. :-) Back to the question itself: in Italian “*bizzarro* [something]” apparently just means that that something is an especially curious, weird, unusual specimen of its category. A common housecat might be *bizzarro* as well as a purple, flying unicorn (some of these might well be weirder than other ones).

Comment: @JeanB It seems to me that you have completely understood the meaning of the sentence (a bizarre killer) and you just think the sentence itself is badly written. I am afraid that you will have to take this complaint to Baglione himself...

Comment: Okay, then. Let's chalk this up to _bizzarro_ Baglione, and thanks to all for your comments.

Comment: I must apologise, since I checked the meaning of *ammazzatore* in the old Crusca vocabulary, but not of *bizzarro* itself. And apparently in times past [it could also mean](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=BIZZARRO) “*iracondo, stizzoso*”, i.e. irascible, easily offended (in addition to “*capriccioso*”, which had a meaning nearer to the modern one of *bizzarro*, and “*vivace and spiritoso*”, lively and witty). And actually, of a horse that takes fright we still say that *si è imbizzarrito*. So might that man be someone who killed on a whim, moved by wrath?

Comment: See also http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/bizzarro_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/

Comment: The painter Baglione is talking about was indeed impetuous and irascible, so that makes sense. Thanks for following up on this.

Comment: What about "impromptu killer"? Like a spontaneous, unprepared one. A violent, impulsive person.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the original meaning, in Italian, of the word ”bizzarro” is ”wrathful”: Dante Alighieri used it in this sense in _Inf._ VIII, 62 (“Tutti gridavano: ‘A Filippo Argenti!’; / e ‘l fiorentino spirito bizzarro / in sé medesmo si volvea co’ denti.”).  After having a glance to a couple of dictionaries, it seems that it is not clear where the current meaning of “peculiar, strange, bizarre” arose from.

Comment: BTW, “one of his contemporaries” should be Michelangelo Merisi da Caravaggio, isn’t he?

Comment: I’ve found that it’s not Caravaggio, but Tommaso Luini.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. His name was actually Tommaso Dovini (1601-1637), sometimes called Luini, and nicknamed Caravaggino in reference to Caravaggio because of his dark palette and his violent temper. Last April I published a novel set in 17th century Rome entitled _Caravaggino_ (https://caravaggino.wordpress.com). That's why I posted the question a while back, and I really appreciate the answers and comments I've received. By the way, the French publisher is trying to get this book translated in Italian, in case you have suggestions (Newton Compton Editori didn't take it).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**  Only after having posted this answer did I notice [DaG’s comment](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7391/translation-for-bizzarro-ammazzatore-1642/8360#comment15319_7391), which points to exactly the same information; I’d like both to apologize for this, and to make it clear that I had drawn this information from a totally different source (a printed edition of the *Commedia*).  I’ll probably remove this answer after a short grace period (some 48 hours).

---

The use of the word “bizzarro” dates back at least to Dante Alighieri, who used it (once) in his *Commedia*, more precisely in *Inf.* VIII, 62:

> Tutti gridavano: «A Filippo Argenti!»;
>   e ‘l fiorentino spirito bizzarro
>   in sé medesmo si volvea co’ denti.

We are, here, in the fifth circle, where the sinners of wrath are punished.  As a matter of fact, even the Italian annotators of the fourteenth century were rather puzzled by the word, and did not completely agree on its meaning.  Boccaccio wrote about it:

> Credo questo vocabolo sia solo dei fiorentini,
>   e suona sempre in mala parte; perciocché noi tegnamo bizzarri
>   coloro che subitamente e per ogni piccola cagione corrono in ira,
>   né mai da quella per alcuna dimostrazione rimuovere si possono.

That is, more or less (please forgive my poor translation): “I believe that this word belongs to Florentines alone, and it always has a negative connotation; because we deem *bizzarri* those who suddenly and for every slightest reason rush into wrath, neither they can be turned away from it, whatever evidence they are given”.

Comment: Please leave this answer, and feel free to add to it anything you should deem useful from my comment, to finally have a good answer for this question.

Comment: Ciao! No need to remove your answer.